# How to serve static folder on every route with ASP.NET core 5 in C#?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

Right now I use

```cs
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

with `UseWebRoot("./public");`

to serve public folder on `/` route.

Which contains

```
index.html
bundle.js
```

If I use the `/nested` route it will look for the `nested` folder inside my file server.

If I use `app.UseSpa()` with `app.UseSpaStaticFiles();` or `return File("index.html", "text/html");` on every route it will serve every file from the public folder as `index.html`.

How do I configure so that I can serve the same public folder with default files on every route?

For example if I request `/nested/route` i want to still serve `public` folder which will render as `index.html` in that folder, not `public/nested/route` folder.

Comment: Is it a SPA project?

Comment: @FeiHan it is a web api template

Comment: why do you need index.html in WEB API project?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I've typo'd, I created just a web project and that is because first I wanted a very basic template so I could build everything from the ground up. Second `dotnet new` templates have a lot of unnessesary code, not suitable for an application that i need. Third the is no `spa` template, only `angular` and `react` ones. Fourth those `react` template don't work from the box, they error. Fifth i want to learn C#, so i wanted to create a minimalistic template that doesn't use any specific front-end framework, rather just use `index.html` as a starting point.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk also what does it matter whether i need index.html or don't in my __WEB API__ project, that's just a name, it's not a project it's just a template, no?

Comment: It's WEB API, you should not have any frontend (html/js/css) files because there is only JSON response. You can see the difference using `dotnet new mvc` and `dotnet new webapi`

Comment: @RomanMarusyk so you say I physically cannot return an HTML with WEB API template?

Comment: Of course, physically you can. But it is not related to the question.